# Does Google Cloud include Google Workspace?

Tags: cloud, google

Complete newbie, please help me - seems a simple question but I can't find the answer online. If I decide to use Google Cloud to host my Wordpress.com site, is Google Workspace included or do I have to pay for that separately? Thanks.

Comment: It's paid for separately.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm a user of Google Workspace and Google Cloud, and they are paid separately.

Think it like this: for Google Workspace you are forced to have a domain name, but you're not for GCP. For Google Workspace, you need to create a new Google account, but you can use Google Cloud with your @gmail.com one.